# Solve linear equation with 2 unkown and 3 equations in numpy with np.linalg.solve

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra, linear-equation

3 euqations with two unknow have 3 solutions: One solution, infinte solutions, no solution.
How would you write this in Numpy
to get the solutions?
I tried it the way you would do it with 3 unknowns:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([-9,-8, 14])

A = np.array([[ 1, 2, -2],
              [-3,-1, 4],
              ])
x = np.linalg.solve(A, a)
print(x)
```

But gives an Error, as A is not square. Sadly if I remove the last column of a and A, although i get an answer the system might still have no solution as it might not fit in the third equation.

Comment: Your input is invalid. You have given numpy 2 equations `A` and 3 solutions `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do all this using the `lstsq` method. For example,

```
a = np.array([-9,-8, 14])
A = np.array([[ 1, 2, -2],
              [-3,-1, 4],
              ])
x,err,rk = np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, a)[:3]
print(x)
print(err)
print(rk)
```

yields the output

```
[-3.  2.]
[9.98402083e-31]
2
```

From the fact that the error is zero (up to numerical precision), you know that this solution is exact, which is to say that `A.T@x` should exactly equal `a`. So, the system has at least one solution.

From the fact that the rank is 2 (which matches the number of columns in `A.T`), we deduce that `A.T` has a trivial nullspace, which means that any solutions are unique.

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/numpy/example/16034/find-the-least-squares-solution-to-a-linear-system-with-np-linalg-lstsq